# Next.js 13 all pages are server-side render bug

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

All pages in next 13 (experimental app.dir) are server side rendered λ. 
Doesn't matter if there is any fetching inside them.
Only slug pages with `generateStaticParams` are automatically generated as static.

For example: 
`app/test/page.tsx`

```
const page = () => {
  return <h1> test page</h1>;
};

export default page;
```

Output after running `npm run build`

```
Route (app)                                   Size     First Load JS
┌ λ /                                         0 B                0 B
├ λ /about-me                                 172 B          71.6 kB
├ λ /backend                                  189 B          89.3 kB
├ λ /backend/[post]                           139 B          66.8 kB
├ λ /frontend                                 189 B          89.3 kB
├ ● /frontend/[post]                          1.4 kB         68.1 kB
├   ├ /frontend/post1
├   ├ /frontend/post2
├   └ /frontend/post3
└ λ /test                                     139 B          66.8 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all                 66.7 kB
  ├ chunks/17-07dd3c6388d7c9b8.js             64 kB
  ├ chunks/main-app-f7991bdf5a7d528d.js       200 B
  └ chunks/webpack-25c60cf3849dbdaa.js        2.52 kB

Route (pages)                                 Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /404                                      179 B          81.5 kB
└ λ /api/hello                                0 B            81.3 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all                 81.3 kB
  ├ chunks/main-c47fccc8bf0082d4.js           78.6 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-9f5490aa3d56632f.js     192 B
  └ chunks/webpack-25c60cf3849dbdaa.js        2.52 kB

λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
●  (SSG)     automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)
```

`next.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
    fontLoaders: [
      {
        loader: '@next/font/google',
        options: {
          subsets: ['latin'],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  images: {
    domains: ['media.graphassets.com', 'avatars.githubusercontent.com'],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

`layout.tsx`

```
import { Roboto } from '@next/font/google';
import { Footer } from './components/footer/Footer';
import { Nav } from './components/nav/Nav';
import { Providers } from './providers';
import './styles/globals.scss';

const font = Roboto({
  weight: ['400', '500', '700'],
});

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html className={font.className} lang="en">
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <Providers>
          <Nav />
          {children}
          <Footer />
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Dont understand why pages are not ssg by default as it should be .
I'm trying to make a simple blog using next.js, graphQL and hygraphCMS.
In blog everything that can should be server side generated but my project is broken.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am having the same issue with my project

Comment: Try replacing the layout with an empty one that returns only `{children}`. Try also returning an empty page for `/`. If everything suddenly turns SSG, start adding elements until you find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the cookies() or headers() function anywhere in those pages? This will make the page dynamic. If not, you can enforce static pages via  https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config